# Session Timeout in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

In my application i am facing session timeout issue . What happens is that suddenly users kicked out . I surf alot for solution and did many things . Like increasing session timeout , idle timeout ,implemented keepalive . But issue still exists 
Is it possible that its due to internet connectivity . Because i saw multiple time in console that `net::Error` connection-reset , Network-changed  etc etc.

If yes then what could be the possible solution for this .

Thanks,

Comment: If using SQL Server as database you can opt for SQL Server Session State. Here's the link [SQL Server Session State Management](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604)

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout is controlled by the following key in web.config...

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: yes you are right but i set timeout to `180` means 3 hours and its getting out sometimes after an hour , sometimes after half an hour

Comment: Try upping the session timeout value in IIS. The default value for that is 20 minutes. You could set the web.config to have the session timeout in 4 years, but the IIS session timeout will override it. Assuming your users are not being active on your site

Comment: as mentioned in question i already set idle timeout and idle timeout is `190` and session timeout in IIS is '180' .

Comment: ok sorry, i have seen where the app-pool recycled rate causes this.  For some reason the authentication cookie becomes invalid because the encryption/decryption keys change. And so your site is not able to read the authentication cookie anymore.

Comment: Check out this link. https://mysoftwarenotes.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/asp-net-timouts-sessions-and-app-pools-and-auths-oh-my/